# Getting water depth data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, import, garmin, copernicus

I'm working on water path planning in QGIS (for example, least cost path in a river). Now it contains only xy coordinates. Is there a way to get data on the water depth in QGIS? For example, any open data sources like Copernicus or OSM that can be loaded in QGIS (at least inaccurate)? I tried to import data from a Garmin navigator into QGIS, but I couldn’t do this (and I have an error when I tried to open it in official Garmin software too).

Comment: For what geographical region?

Comment: For the White Sea region, mostly for the river that goes into the sea

Comment: Do you actually have any data on water depth? If you have, then let us know what format it is in and someone will be able to tell you how to get it into QGIS. If you haven't then address this problem first.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for bathymetric data, that is, the topography of the seabed. As a general remark, bathymetric data is taken using [echo-sounders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_sounding). As echo-sounders cannot be satellite-borne, but require a ship going over the survey area, bathymetric data is generally a lot more scarce than data pertaining to land areas, where satellites can be used for automated, high-volume data generation.

Specifically for your area of interest:

- Check the [digital data store](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/maps/iho_dcdb/) of the International Hydrographic Organization
- [This publication reviews geophysical data on the White Sea region.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/345975638_The_White_Sea_Available_Data_and_Numerical_Models) It mentions the scarcity of data for this region, but also cites a number of sources which the authors used, so check those out as well.
- Finally, while not open-source, but it could be worth getting in touch with related state agencies and/or shipping companies operating in the area. If there is a decent amount of riverine/maritime shipping in the area, then there should be at least some rudimentary data to mark safe shipping routes.

For the Garmin import problem I suggest you make a new post, as it is a technical problem quite unrelated to the availability of digital bathymetric data.